# Strange behavior styling a button in firefox

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have this css style to make circle buttons for bootstrap 4

```
.btn-circle {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 6px 0px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;
}
```

And this is the html used

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary btn-circle"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i></button>
```

Using chrome browser works fine, but when I do click using firefox version 78.4 the button's background is filled with btn-primary class background color resulting in a square button for a very short time.

Have tried with pseudo classes like this

```
.btn-primary.btn-circle:hover:active:focus {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

but no luck.

So, How can I fix this behavior in firefox?

---

### Update:

If I remove .btn-primary class the button's background is filled in white color; but don't really know what css rule is causing this behavior in firefox.

Answer (score 0):

to solve this add margin to this class **.btn-circle**

also bootstrap button css is applied to **.btn-circle**  to avoid that use **.btn.btn-circle** class like this

```css
.btn.btn-circle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 6px 0px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
margin: 10px;
}

.btn-primary.btn-circle:hover:active:focus {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-circle"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i></button>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Vikas. Tried your suggestion; but doesn't solve the issue. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening of `box-shadow` property which is taken by default from `bootstrap-4`.

So you have to just override that css with your custom css.

```css
.btn-primary.btn-circle {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 6px 0px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;
    outline:none;
}
.btn-primary.btn-circle.focus, .btn-primary.btn-circle:focus, .btn-primary.btn-circle:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus{
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-circle"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i></button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Jignesh. Tried your suggestion; but doesn't solve the issue. I have updated the question.